# Functional Equations and information theory: $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x,y\in[0,1]$

Tags: functional-equations

What is the solution of the functional equation $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$  for all $x$ and $y$ in $I$ where $f$ is a real-valued mapping with domain the unit closed interval $I$?

Comment: Why have you used "Information Theory" in the title?

Comment: $f(x)=x^a$ for some $a>0$. But you need some regularity assumption on $f$, e.g. continuity.

Comment: For example, $f(x)=1$ for all $x$ , or $f(x)=1$  for all $x\ne0$, and $f(0)=0$.

Comment: See the "$f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$" section under the canonical answer to [Overview of basic facts about Cauchy functional equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation).

Answer (score 0):

It is not full solution but it can help you solve it fully (if I solve it fully I will edit this).
Take $y=x$, then $f(x^2)=f(x)^2$.
Take the derivative of both sides.
$$f'(x^2) \cdot 2x = 2f(x) \cdot f'(x)$$
$$f'(x^2) \cdot x=f(x) \cdot f'(x)$$
1) If $f'(x) = 0$, then $f(x) = C$, where $C$ is some real number.
Then from the functional equation we get $C = C^2$. Solving this equation we get $C=0$ or $C=1$. Then $f(x) = 0$ or $f(x) = 1$.

2) $f'(x) \ne 0$
Then we can get such a differential equation:
$$f(x)=\frac{f'(x^2) \cdot x}{f'(x)}$$

Comment: But it was not given that $f$ is differentiable. If it is *continuous*, which is a less demanding requirement, then one can prove that it's a power function, see the quoted answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: Oh, yeah I didn't think about that